# Bulk Download All invoices

Tags: pdf, printing, netsuite, invoice, bulk-load

Is there a way to download all invoices in Netsuite? We have around 50K invoices. The 'print checks & Forms' page has a limitation of 100 invoices. Is there a way to overcome this? I need individual copies of all invoices.

Comment: If you have NetSuite Analitycs  you can download via ODBC

Comment: Do you need the data from the invoices or the PDFs? If the data do you need it to the line level? Is this a one time thing or ongoing?